# Display 4th level category thumbs

Tags: html

I have the code the gets the levels 1 - 3 displaying as desired - What would be needed to display the 4th level?

> (1)/exhibitions(2)/past(3)/2019(4?)/
>   https://www.waterstreetgallery.co.uk/en/exhibitions/past/2019/

There is an image added for that category and I have tried using `{% for sub in **sub**subCat.subs %}` but no joy..

```
<!-- 1stlevel -->
  {% for category in shop.categories %}
    {% if category.id == collection.category_id and category.subs %}
    <div class="parenter grid-cell mb3 {% if category.url == exhibitions %}exhibitionsGrid{% endif %}">
      <div class="grid column-orient">
        <div class="grid-cell">
          <div class="grid wrap col-filtered relative">
          {% for sub in category.subs %}
          {% if sub.image %}
          <div class="grid-cell grow0 col-products_product already-visible come-in">
            <div class="subcatimage">
              <a href="{{ sub.url | url }}">
                <img class="image" src="{{ sub.image | url_image() }}">
                <div>{{ sub.title | t }}</div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>         
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
    <!-- 1stlevel -->
    <!--  2nd/3rdlevel  -->
  {% set collectionTitle = collection.internal.url | split('/') %}
  {% if collectionTitle[1] %}
  {% for category in shop.categories %}
  {% for subCat in category.subs %}
  {% if subCat.id == collection.category_id and subCat.subs %}
  <div class="parenter grid-cell mb3 {% if category.url == exhibitions %}exhibitionsGrid{% endif %}">
    <div class="grid column-orient">
      <div class="grid-cell">
        <div class="grid wrap col-filtered relative">
        {% for sub in subCat.subs %}
        {% if sub.image %}
        <div class="grid-cell grow0 col-products_product already-visible come-in">
          <div class="subcatimage">
            <a href="{{ sub.url | url }}">
              <img class="image" src="{{ sub.image | url_image() }}">
              <div>{{ sub.title | t }}</div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
    <!--  2nd/3rdlevel  -->
```

With the correct code added to collection.rain the category image this category would show on the page before - 
https://www.waterstreetgallery.co.uk/en/exhibitions/past/2019/February-March/

Here

https://www.waterstreetgallery.co.uk/en/exhibitions/past/2019/

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: This doesn't seem like a CSS question... are your tags correct?

Comment: Looks like django

Comment: It is .rain https://ecom-support.lightspeedhq.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000277594-3-b-Rain-variables